# How do you wait for the correct result of a method call?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, promise, swift3

I've got a method that, due to the computational load of the problem, sometimes takes several seconds to return the result. Note that this is purely an 'offline' issue and the function makes no calls to web based APIs.

Currently, whenever I ask for the return of the method it just returns nil as it is still working on the function on another thread.

How can I write a function that waits for the correct, non-nil response of the function?

Comment: Don't wait. Make the computing function notify when it is finished.

Comment: @vadian. Can you show any examples? Surely this just puts the problem further upstream, but it's the same problem right?

Comment: It is the same problem but unlike polling (waiting) it doesn't waste any resources.

Comment: "Surely this just puts the problem further upstream" Absolutely not. When you wait within a function you will block execution of that thread, if that function call is made within the GUI then to the user your app has hung and cannot respond to user input. If you implement it properly using a block (closure) or delegate etc. to notify the calling code when the operation is complete then this blocking does not happen.

Comment: Did you have a look at Apple's "Concurrency Programming Guide"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use GCD to dispatch time consuming block to a background thread. The main thing here is not to block the main thread with hard tasks.

**Swift 3 example:**

```
func doSomethingTimeConsuming(completion: ((Any)->Void)?) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        //do time consuming task in here (background thread)
        //let result = ...
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //use callback here (main thread)
            //let's assume the result of your calculation is some object or struct
            completion?(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Replace `Any` with actual result type you expect from your function.

**Usage:**

```
doSomethingTimeConsuming { result in
    //this closure will be called when your time consuming function completes execution
}
```

Comment: Yeah this seems promising, but the problem is that the result of the time consuming function is also the main feature of the view so not much can happen until that has been taken care of. Could I use the completion handler to look for a result on the main thread instead?

Comment: @JamesStonehill Check the update version if you want to get a result of your computations in the callback.